# How to redirect after login in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm used to working on laravel 5.4 and above, i just got this project with a problem in authentification that is rather weird.
Locally, the authentification works just fine but when i try to log using the project on prod i always get redirected to login page.
this is the login function:

```
public function loginadmin()
{
    $pseudo = Input::get('pseudo');
    $pass = Input::get('pass');

    $user = Admin::where('pseudo',$pseudo)->where('pass',$pass)->get()->first();
    if($user){
      Auth::admin()->loginUsingId( $user->id );
      return Redirect::back();
    }
    else{
      Session::flash('errorAuth', "ok");
      return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

this is the routes.php

```
 /* Connexion */
Route::get('admin-igd', function(){ 
  if( !Auth::admin()->get())
    return View::make('admin.login');

  return Redirect::to('admin-igd/slider');
});
```

and this is the filters.php:

```
 Route::filter('loginadmin', function($route, $request)
 {
if ( !Auth::admin()->get()) {
    return Redirect::to('admin-igd');
}
 });
```

Comment: Anything in logs? Environments are different, maybe there is a problem with files/folders privileges

Comment: where can i find the logs ?

Comment: `app/storage/logs/` if you didn't change logging logic

Comment: no error is shown there

Answer (score 0):

Try once after executing below command on your project.

php artisan route:clear

Comment: my project is on production not local can that still be done ?